# Getting an ambiguous error on overloaded ActionResults?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two ActionResults, one that takes in one parameter and one that takes in two parameters. When calling the ActionResult passing in one parameter, I get an error that that the ActionResult is ambiguous between the two.

Why would that be?

```
public ActionResult Edit_ClockGroup(int id)
{
    var vm = new ClockGroupViewModel();
    vm = DAL.GetClockGroupDetail(id);

    return View(vm);
}


public ActionResult Edit_ClockGroup(int id, int readerId)
{
    var vm = new ClockGroupViewModel();
    vm = DAL.GetClockGroupDetail(id, readerId);

    return View(vm);            
}
```

I guess I could use the ActionResult with two parameters and then set the optional parameter with a default value but for my knowledge I'm trying to understand why this would be ambiguous when there are two different ActionResults that take in different parameters?

Comment: probably because you can still call the first action `GetClockGroupDetail(int groupId)` and pass 2 parameters, and it would still work as long as one of the parameters is `groupId`

Comment: You have a route conflict because most probably you are using the default convention based route `{controller}/{action}/{id}` which would match both the actions in question. You need to uniquely distinguish between those actions to avoid the route conflict.

Comment: Simplest solution is just to have one `public ActionResult Edit_ClockGroup(int id, int? readerId)` method and check `if (readerId.HasVaue) { ...`

Comment: @Muecke...that's basically what I ended up doing. Only difference is I defaulted the  readerId = 0 instead of allowing NULL. Then I just check to make sure readerId > 0 for my conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a route conflict because most probably you are using the default convention based route `{controller}/{action}/{id}` which would match both the actions in question.

You need to uniquely distinguish between those actions to avoid the route conflicts. You can either change the action name or create a new route that takes all the required parameters into consideration.

Comment: I am using the default route and I'm sure this is probably the case but I'm not 100% understanding why. How does it match both? Wouldn't one be Edit_ClockGroup/17 and the other be something like Edit_ClockGroup/17?readerId=85. I also don't know how to specifically distinguish between the two actions. They are named the same and are in the same controller.

Comment: @Caverman review : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: Thanks for the link. I understand the basics of routing but I obviously need more understanding. I'm going to have to go research more about routing with multiple parameters as well as how to uniquely distinguish between the two ActionResults. The easy fix is to change the name of one of the ActionResults but I'm trying to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an ugly way to do it, but you could combine both actions like this

```
public ActionResult Edit_ClockGroup(int id, int? readerId = null)
{
    var vm = readerId.HasValue 
        ?  DAL.GetClockGroupDetail(id, readerId)
        :  DAL.GetClockGroupDetail(id);

    return View(vm);            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does look like it would work but I would probably just default the readerId=0 parameter. That would be similar to what you have. It would just be that the readerId would always be 0 or some ID value. From there I would just have to check for ID > 0 if versus checking for IF(readerId != null).

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I know it works, I've done it in the past. I guess I think it's ugly because it's of the nullable parameter with a default value.  That always felt like a odd way of getting around tradtional method overloading.